# Why is Asp.Net MVC not searching for a view in my Shared directory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

In my `/Views/Shared/` folder I created an `EntityNotFound.cshtml` razor view.  In one of my controller actions I have the following call:

```
return View(MVC.Shared.Views.EntityNotFound, "Company");
```

This causes the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The view '~/Views/Shared/EntityNotFound.cshtml' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>
> ~/Views/Company/Company.cshtml
>
> ~/Views/Company/Company.vbhtml
>
> ~/Views/Shared/Company.cshtml
>
> ~/Views/Shared/Company.vbhtml

I am confused, because it does not even seem to be attempting to search `~/Views/Shared/EntityNotFound.cshtml`.  Even if I replace `MVC.Shared.Views.EntityNotFound` with `"EntityNotFound"` I get the same error.

Why is Asp.Net MVC not even attempting to find my shared view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the list of overloads for `View();`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view.aspx

Specifically, when you pass `View(string,string);` it sees the second string as the name of the master view.

Whats probably happening, is that it can't find the "Company" master view, you'll not the exception messages says

> ... or its master was not found...

Which means that it is probably finding the `NotFoundException.cshtml`, but can't correctly find the `Company.cshtml` that it's looking for as the master.

Comment: Ah, so having a string model is a bad idea :)

Comment: Indeed, you can cheat the system by typecasting the string model to object... so `View("NotFoundException", (object)"Company");`

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax should be this (don't pass path, MVC is a language by conventions)

```
  return View("EntityNotFound");
```

Assuming "Company" is a param you wnat to pass to the view, try like this:

```
  ViewBag.ErrorEntity = "Company";
  return View("EntityNotFound");
```

And from the View

```
  <p>Entity not found: @ViewBag.ErrorEntity</p>
```